# grub2 deadlock situation

Tags: 10.04, grub2, menu, plymouth

During 10.04 starts it does a filesystem check. For some reason that I want to figure out, but this is another question, the harddisk is mounted read only.

I would like to boot to a rescue shell, but the grub2 menu is hidden

I cannot change the grub default config, because I have read only access to the harddisk.

I will now  try and manually mount the harddsik readable to change the grub option.

Is there a secret key combination to:

- show the grub menu anyway during boot?
- make the splash go away during boot and see the interesting console output?

EDIT:

The answer is to hold the shift key, after the Grub Message "Starting Grub" appears.

This is also a good article about understanding grub2 or switching form grub to grub2:

http://maketecheasier.com/mastering-grub-2-the-easy-way/2009/11/19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the Grub menu hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key until it displays.