# How to fix ahead disk mounting / ahead of time problem

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I am booting a 32 bit laptop with ubuntu 10.04.

I see only a splash screen during boot, in the end theer is a message that the main filesystem is mounted read only (there is only one harddisk).

I could grasp a message saying that the last check time of the harddisk is in the future. The message also told me the time that was set there. But the message disappearde to quickly and I cannot bring it back.

I checked cmos time, but it is set to UTC and correct.

(Could it be that somehow my local time and UTC was not applied correctly?)

Where can I see the messages from boot?

- I cannot see them on the secreen because there is only an ubuntu logo while it should display interesting messages (see also [grub2 deadlock situation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34509/grub2-deadlock-situation) where I am asking how to change the boot process )
- dmesg does not show any of the harddsik problems at all
- /var/log/boot is empty (I did not enable bootlogd yet, see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=49925 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Solution taken from question body)*

> On boot I pressed Shift after I saw "GRUB starting", in the grub menu I selected the second entry. I could see from the messages that the problem was on the /boot partition, I ran fsck and fixed it.